# array and loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hey all, I basically need to add a class to every `<option>` in a select. There is a different class to apply depending on the `value` of each option.

I need an easy way of doing something like

```
$('select option').each(function(){

       if($(this).val()=="Argentina"){  $(this).addClass("ar");  }
       if($(this).val()=="Brazil"){  $(this).addClass("br");  }
       if($(this).val()=="Czech"){  $(this).addClass("cz");  }

});
```

I have a very long list of countries, so using an array of some sort would be preferable, and then let the function filter in the `if value =` and the `class name`.

Many thanks

Tim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, use associative array:

```
var mapping = { "Argentina": "ar", "Brazil": "br", "Czech": "cz"};
$('select option').each(function(){
   var sClass = mapping[$(this).val()];
   if (sClass)
      $(this).addClass(sClass);
});
```

The `if (sClass)` is just failsafe to avoid crash when you forget to put country in the array. You can add some default class in such case.

Comment: Thanks Tim and @Raja! Hopefully this will become my first [Nice Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer) ;)

Comment: It sure is an Awesome Answer in my view just requires 3 more votes :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just an extra opinion in case the pattern (*the class is just the first two chars in lowercase*) from the example is a rule.

```
$('select option').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass( this.value.substr(0,2).toLowerCase() );
});
```

Comment: +1 for nice idea but what about (one example out of many) `Ireland` and `Iraq`? :) EDIT: even with 3 letters.. `India` and `Indonesia`

Comment: @shadow, yes i know it it does not hold much water in the official abbreviation of all countries.. I just posted it in case he was using a fixed list and the pattern fit every case..

Comment: Sure @Gaby I'm well aware of that - if this is indeed the case I do believe your way is better.

Comment: Tim: Yeah thanks for this, I was using the A2 ISO Country Codes in this case so it wouldn't have worked like that unfortunately. Thanks nonetheless :)